# How can I expose a WSDL using Mulesoft so Salesforce can call it

Tags: web-services, wsdl, mule

I'm new to the Mulesoft. Currently we have a requirement that need to use Mulesoft to expose a WSDL for Salesforce to call. When Salesforce call this web service, it will transform some account information and Mulesoft will load them to a MySQL table. Could anyone help how can I create this? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Nuno and Anirban. I have knowledge to connect to MYSQL but I'm not sure about the CXF configuration part. My understanding is in the flow, I need to have a HTTP, a CXF, a datamapper and a Database connector. I don't know how to refrence the information that will be received from the call. e.g: When Salesforce call my webservice, they will send me an ID and a Name, I will store them into MySQL. But where I can define the ID and Name? In CXF? I'm really confused about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely... As Nuno said you need to use CXF component in Mule to expose your SOAP webservice.. Actually using Mule platform you can able to expose any kind of Web Service you required like (Soap,Rest) that other applications can able to read ..

Take a look into an easy way of creating the webservice and exposing the WSDL :- http://training.middlewareschool.com/mule/soap-code-first-build/

Comment: How do you get further along after that Java Class? Like perhaps I want to work with the data that was passed through CXF. For example, set it to a variable to use with Salesforce Connecter?

Answer (score 0):

To publish a SOAP service you should use the **CXF component** ([reference](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/CXF+Component+Reference)). Take a look into the documentation [Publishing a SOAP API](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Publishing+a+SOAP+API) to have an ideia in how to begin your flow.

Please take some time to have a quick look into the [Mule User guide](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+User+Guide), since it explains the essentials to start developing with Mule. You will need it to learn how to interact with MySQL too ([Database connector](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Database+Connector)).

Comment: Thanks Nuno. I have knowledge to connect to MYSQL but I'm not sure about the CXF configuration part. My understanding is in the flow, I need to have a HTTP, a CXF, a datamapper and a Database connector. I don't know how to refrence the information that will be received from the call. e.g: When Salesforce call my webservice, they will send me an ID and a Name, I will store them into MySQL. But where I can define the ID and Name? In CXF? I'm really confused about that. Thank you!